# How to edit feature in SQLServer geodatabase

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.2, esri-geodatabase, sql-server

I am using ArcMap 10.2.1 and ArcObjects 10.2.1, I just want to connect to a geodatabase and edit, add, delete a feature from a feature class using ArcObjects, I tried to connect to database and it works fine but I can't start editing and adding a feature to it.

Here is my code:

```
public void open_Workspace()
    {
    Type factoryType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriDataSourcesGDB.SqlWorkspaceFactory");
    IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = (IWorkspaceFactory)Activator.CreateInstance(factoryType);
    IWorkspaceFactory2 workspaceFactory2 = workspaceFactory as IWorkspaceFactory2;
    // Build a connection string.
    String[] connectionProps = 
{
    "dbclient=SQLServer", "serverinstance=CRAZYVIRUS-HP", 
        "database=land_gis", "authentication_mode=OSA" 
};
    String connString = String.Join(";", connectionProps);

    IWorkspace workspace = workspaceFactory2.OpenFromString(connString, 0);
    ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureWorkspace featureWorkspace = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureWorkspace)workspace; // Explict Cast
    ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureClass featureClass = featureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass("DBO.test");

    ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureLayer featureLayer = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.FeatureLayerClass();

    featureLayer.FeatureClass = featureClass;
    featureLayer.Name = featureClass.AliasName;
    featureLayer.Visible = true;

    IWorkspaceEdit workspaceEdit = (IWorkspaceEdit)workspace;
    IWorkspaceEdit2 workspaceEdit2 = (IWorkspaceEdit2)workspaceEdit;
    IMultiuserWorkspaceEdit muWorkspaceEdit = (IMultiuserWorkspaceEdit)workspace;

    Make sure that non-versioned editing is supported. If not, throw an exception.
   if (!muWorkspaceEdit.SupportsMultiuserEditSessionMode
       (esriMultiuserEditSessionMode.esriMESMNonVersioned))
   {
       throw new ArgumentException(
           "The workspace does not support non-versioned editing.");
   }

   // Start a non-versioned edit session.
   muWorkspaceEdit.StartMultiuserEditing
   (esriMultiuserEditSessionMode.esriMESMNonVersioned);

    featureClass.CreateFeature();


    // Stop the edit session. The saveEdits parameter indicates the edit session
    // will be committed.
    workspaceEdit.StopEditing(true);

}
```

When I run above code I got this error `Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IWorkspaceEdit2'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{199A1F9D-435A-4118-9B3F-4E0B8F984AA0}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).`

I tried to enable versioning or disable it but there is not any chance to make it work...  Can you help me find the solution into this error?
Is there any thing wrong with my connection?

Comment: I've no experience with SQLserver in this manner, however for PostgreSQL you use an IPropertySet to connect. Be sure that your IWorkspace supports IWorkspaceEdit, I have a suspicion that it may not, hence the error. I'm confused about the Activator.CreateInstance here, can you confirm that is correct... normally it would be *IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = new SqlWorkspaceFactory();* but like I said, no experience in this, it may not be a problem.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson You know..I am new with arcobject :( but I can connect to database and work with feature layer with this code..Can you halp me and share an example code that you use with postsql?Maybe I get an idea how to make this code works. thanks

Comment: I don't use SqlWorkspaceFactory I use SDEworkspaceFactory http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/SdeWorkspaceFactoryClass_Class/001m00000035000000/ then IWorkspaceFactory.Open using an IPropertySet with the connection details. Not every workspace type will support all methods. I think that returned workspace does not support IWorkspaceEdit2, stick with IWorkspaceEdit.

Comment: I am sure this is just a snippet because your featureClass just appears from nowhere. CreateFeature() returns an IFeature which needs to have the Store() invoked before it actually appears in the database. This works but I recommend using IFeatureBuffer / IFeatureCursor / IFeatureClass.InsertCursor() and .CreateFeatureBuffer() - not much more effort and faster.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Yes I am trieng to learn how edit feature and then use in in my code,So what key words do I search to find about this  IFeatureBuffer and other interfeces,and also I tried to use SDEworkspaceFactory before but I faced lots of errors :(I asked a question about it here:http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104656/connecting-to-sql-server-geodatabase-using-arcobject-in-c

Comment: I was on holiday when you posted that question. If you have ArcObjects then you have the developer help, go to the index and type in the object name. You could google it but that will return different versions. BTW according to the docs the SqlWorkspaceFactory supports IWorkspaceEdit and IWorkspaceEdit2 so you shouldn't be getting that error, try creating it without the activator like I mentioned before. The property set, as shown in the post, is how I have connected previously.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Thanks for your helps friend,So you mean I can use it without ARCSDE installed?Is my error related to versioning or sth like that?

Comment: You should be able to use SqlWorkspace.. in the docs http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/SqlWorkspaceFactoryClass_Class/001m00000037000000/ it says you should be using SDEworkspaceFactory to connect, but I can't find anythng else about it; is your SqlServer ArcSDE personal?

Answer (score 1):

I think @MichaelMiles-Stimson is right and you should use the SdeWorkspaceFactory instead of SqlWorkspaceFactory and then solve the following errors you mentioned.

The examples are [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//001m00000039000000) and this way works in our project.

Comment: Thanks for your help..Can you give me a source to setup arcsde?I installed in on client side but I cant connect to it..Is is client side?or server side?

Comment: ArcSDE is part of ArcGis server **enterprise** and is **very** expensive. If it is an option then you must get the client libraries to suit your database from Esri support. The SqlWorkspaceFactory exists but *might* only support tables, therefore not the IWorkspaceEdit. I would do more research into it unless of course you already have SDE.

Comment: Yes, you definitely must have the server side to connect as to SDE. ArcSDE itself is also known as ArcGIS for Server Basic (Enterprise or Workgroup) and also is a part of greater products. You can contact your local ESRI distributor to get a test license or buy a Term license, it is cheaper. Another way to test is try to use ArcSDE Personal which comes with ArcGIS for Desktop Standard or Advanced (You need to have at least Standard license to edit SDE data).

Comment: @gnevan thanks for your good information,I think I can not have SDE licence so I must find a way to connect to geoserver and edit featureclasses ..I can edit tabels using native sql server abilities but I ned editing features..The only way to do this is using SDE?I have ArcMap Advance licence so this is why I can connect to database using arcmap without any problem but can not connect using my arcEngine application:(

Comment: I don't understand what database or what features you want to edit if you don't have SDE?

Comment: @gnevan sorry I did not get your mean :(,I have a remote Sql server and I have created a geodatabase in it.I can connect it using above connection and I can query the only FeatureClass in that database using this connection,It is a polygon shape file indeed, I want to edit this polygon and add,edit,delete features in this feature class but I dont know how to do this without using ARCSDE connection,Is it ever possible?

Comment: If you've created a feature class in a geodatabase then you have all you need to edit the data. You don't need to install ArcSDE on the server. Just try to use SDEWorkspaceFactory instead of SqlWorkspaceFactory and connect with the parameters you use to connect with the Desktop application.

Comment: @gnevan I have created feature using ArcMap and I can connect to database using arcCatalog in Arcmap and It works fine.So you mean using SDEWorksapce doesnt require any Sde installetion on serverside or client?But when I try to connect to db using SDEWorkspaceFactory I get error that cant find sde server :( I'll try more and will say here the results,